# Обработка длинного url

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Есть длинный `url`, который разбирается через регулярные выражения и передается в скрипт в виде набора параметров. Проблема появляется начиная с $10 замены, почему то берется значение $1 и к нему добавляется 0. Как быть? Разбирать `url` в скрипте не предлагать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Больше 9 обратных ссылок использовать в mod_rewrite нельзя. Это сказано в официальной документации.
Можно обрабатывать несколькими правилами с передачей необработанной части следующему правилу. ($9 это необработанный остаток)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)-(.*?)-(.*?)-(.*?)-(.*?)-(.*?)-(.*?)-(.*?)-(.*) req.php=$1=$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8=$9 [C]
RewriteRule (.*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ $1=$2=$3 [C]
RewriteRule ^([^=]*)=(.*) $1?$2
```

Это немного кривой пример, но наглядный.
Первое правило заменяет первые восемь тире на равенство.
Второе правило заменяет последние два тире на равенство.
Третье правило заменяет первое = на ?, чтобы все это корректно работало.
Введя например в адресной строке

```
http://localhost/1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14
```

то PHP в `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] получит

```
1=2=3=4=5=6=7=8=9-10-11-12=13=14
```

Но все это мне кажется быдлокодие, гораздо лучше обрабатывать запрос к серверу в самом скрипте уже.

Comment: Так пробовал, не работает, передается для 10 параметра значение ${10}

Comment: Во всех официальных документах по mod_rewrite пишут, что больше 9 нельзя указывать обратную ссылку. Значит не такой уж он и перл-совместимый.

Comment: А у Вас фактически все группы от 1 до 9 используются? Может быть стоит попробовать ненужные группы делать несохраняющими `(?:re)`

Comment: Да их там даже больше 9 используется. Пришлось до 9 их сократить, и уже в скрипте разбирать оставшиеся параметры. Удивлен таким странным ограничением в 9 групп.

Comment: Можно попробовать размещать два правила rewriterule подряд. Разбирать девять параметров, а остальное просто оставить как есть.  
Вторым правилом разбирать следующие девять параметров.  
П.С. Это моя фантазия. Не знаю насколько это реально :)

Comment: @зоркий просто шаблоны вида ${текст} mod_rewrite воспринимает как переменные окружения. А это косяк создателей этого мода, так как это конфликтует с PCRE.

Comment: Да, да спасибо я по ссылке выше всё это уже прочитал в документации :)